# how to call WebSocket Function through useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

const [user, setUser] = useState([{
connected: false
}]);

```
const connect = () => {
    console.log("going to connect")
    let Sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:9081/gs-guide-websocket');
    stompClient = over(Sock);
    stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
    console.log("connect SUccessfull");
}
 useEffect(()=>{
    connect();
     console.log(user);
 },[user]);
```

This is my code.here i want to call websocket through useEffect().and want tot update user for every updation of user. display it on the ui.it's givig me an error at the second argument of useEffect().

Comment: What's the exact error? Your question needs clarification. And correct code formatting, too.

Comment: from my above code i want to call a websocket which will continuously fetch data from backend and will render to ui. so how  should i call my websocket connection with the help of React hooks.